# Capture first line of NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How do I capture the first line from a NSString object?

I currently am assigning the entire NSString object to the title of my textView, but only want to assign the first line of the string. My current code like this this:

```
self.textView.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"taskText"] description];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want

```
self.textView.text = [[[[managedObject valueForKey: @"taskText"] description] componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: Since `-componentsSeparatedByString:` returns an `NSArray` instance, you cannot use the C-array `[]` syntax. You need to send `-objectAtIndex:` instead.

Comment: Also, since there are multiple representations for newlines, you should use `-componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` with `+[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]`.

Comment: What if there are 10,000 lines and you just want to peel off the first line without parsing out the other 9,999 lines?

Answer (score 6):

If you’re targeting iOS 4.0 and later, you can use `-[NSString enumerateLinesUsingBlock:]`:

```
__block NSString *firstLine = nil;
NSString *wholeText = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"taskText"] description];
[wholeText enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString *line, BOOL *stop) {
    firstLine = [[line retain] autorelease];
    *stop = YES;
}];

self.textView.text = firstLine;
```

Comment: Is there something that explains why the little retain/autorelease dance is necessary when assigning to firstLine? I assume this is due to the block pool(?) getting flushed, but have yet to read anything that actually describes this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach which is probably the most efficient and straightforward:

`NSString* str = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"taskText"] description];
 self.textView.text = [str substringWithRange:[str lineRangeForRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)]];`